# How to make maven site build the correct links to the project modules

Tags: java, maven-2, report, pom.xml

I have a maven multimodule project when I try to build the site, it creates the links in the main page with the module name, but the href points to http://maven.apache.com

How do I make either mvn site-deploy or mvn site:site site:deploy construct the right links? because the folder with the sub-site gets created the only issues is it is not linked.

Its driving me insane.

Parent pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test.services</groupId>
<artifactId>contract-lookup</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Contract Lookup Service</name>
<modules>
    <module>child-A</module>
</modules>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.sp1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-webdav</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-repo</id>
        <name>release repo</name>
        <url>http://serverrepo/nexus/content/repositories/twg-maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <site>
        <id>maven.site</id>
        <name>TWG Contract Lookup Service</name>
        <url>dav:http://serverrepo/sites-dav/test/${project.version}</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
                <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

child pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test.service.contract</groupId>
<artifactId>contract-lookup-service-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>${project.parent.version}</version>
<name>contract-lookup-service-web</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>contract-lookup</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>contract-lookup-service-web-${project.version}</finalName>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
                <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative links are calculated based on the value of the `<url>` element in the POM. Here, you just get the link that you specified in the `<url>` element of the POM of `child-A`. Remove this element and it will work (you should specify the proper URL in the parent actually).